# How to refactor this switch statement?

Tags: c#, refactoring, switch-statement

```
string liquidClass = string.Empty;

switch (cmbLiquidClass.Text)
{
    case "LiquidClass1":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass1;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass2":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass2;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass3":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass3;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass4":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass4;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass5":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass5;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass6":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass6;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass7":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass7;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass8":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass8;
        break;
    case "LiquidClass9":
        liquidClass = Settings.Default.LiquidClass9;
        break;
}
```

Trying to get in to a local variable the contents of the current class. I can't use a dictionary because of the way strings work (behaving like value types). Is there any way to refactor this so that it doesn't require this many lines to find the chosen liquid class?

Comment: Use an array and a for-loop?

Comment: _Why_ can't you use a `Dictionary`?

Comment: @ATaylor: Isn't it the case that you cannot store collections in the Settings file?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because of the way strings work. duh.

Comment: Where do you get datasource for your combobox?

Comment: @JohnSmith you can store anything serializeable in a settings file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the indexer that is part of `Settings.Default` (tested with .Net 4.0):

```
var liquidClass = Settings.Default[cmbLiquidClass.Text].ToString();
```

Comment: Beat me to it, was going to suggest the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You could convert this to a dictionary easily using some lambda magic.

```
Dictionary<string, Func<string>> stringsToSettings = new ...
stringsToSettings.Add("LiquidClass1", () => Settings.Default.LiquidClass1);

var liquidClass = stringsToSettings["LiquidClass1"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking into a way of "converting" a string into a class name.

You could use reflection, which allows you to find a class by name, but it's slow and if you ever decide to rename your class in a future version, your code will not work.

Another way is having at some point of initialization a lookup Dictionary (the curse word!) which binds each class to a string.