# Can you return the stored string in settings class?

Tags: c#, string, class

```
public object ReturnSqlScript(string token)
{
    object script = "";
    Type settingsType = typeof(Settings);
    foreach (var propertyInfo in settingsType.GetProperties())
       {
           try
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.Name.Contains(token))
                    {
                        script = propertyInfo.GetValue(propertyInfo, null);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
      }
            return script;
}
```

I have a bunch of SQL Scripts stored in Settings and this method allows me to get the Name of them by matching it to a token (eg. `SqlScript2`) however when I try to get the string value stored in `SqlScript2` it will return "System.String SqlScript 2" rather than the value stored in it. Can I adjust the `GetValue` method to return my stored string?

Comment: What exception? You are returning an `object` rather than a `string` - is this deliberate?

Comment: When I return the string it will return System.String.SqlScript2, I though changing to object could help but didn't change anything. I need it to return System.Settings.SqlScript2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up documentation but have you tried?

```
var script = Settings.Default[token].ToString();
```

I had already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868951/4068).

Comment: Thanks heaps! I just had to enter it as var script = Settings.Default[token].ToString();